# iPhone server-client application

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services

I'm not sure this question is appropriate here but I hope I could get some help. What i'm looking to do is basically to make a server based iPhone application. I've got an ubuntu server ready to be used. I'm thinking of making a web service which my application then can use but I have virtually no experience in this field so i'm looking for some help to get pointed into the right direction, what language to write the web service in etc. It isn't required to be a web service but anything that make's the iPhone app depending on the server.

This little mission is simply for learning experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably PHP is what you will use to write the webservice.  REST based services are the most popular, but it could be as simple as a form POST passing in parameters.  The PHP script (no matter which way you write it), will then pass those parameters and any other needed info to a server method that either executes a SQL query (preferably using a stored procedure) or uses some other server resource.  That data would then be output via the webservice as either XML or JSON (I personally like JSON better).

Check out [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app) tutorial on just this kind of thing:

When it comes time to handle the request in iOS, my personal choice is AFNetworking.  It uses blocks instead of delegate methods and is blazing fast.  I can hook you up with examples if needed.

Comment: Do you have any other example of a server based iPhone app, besides web services?

Comment: Well a web-service is really nothing more than a server side interface that pulls in a request and outputs a response.  It could be a form POST, a full blown REST service or somewhere in between.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, First you need to learn how to write web services in PHP. Which will return you response in XML format. I personally prefer .PLIST format because it gets easier to parse on the iOS.

Once your web services are up and running. You need to use NSURLConnection and NSURLRequest to  talk to your web services. Implementing the NSURLConnection Delegate methods correctly, you can download your XML response, maybe save it in a file on your Documents Directory.

Then once done downloading start parsing that response using NSXMLParser. implementing the delegates and what not, you can create your data structure the way you feel comfortable with manipulating it and store the parsed results in them and populate your View accordingly.

Comment: If he implements the webservice, he can return the response in whatever format he wants. JSON parses faster on iOS than XML does, anyways.

Comment: true, i personally use .PLIST so i dont have to do any sort of parsing at all. Just save it as a file and read it back in a NSDictionary or NSArray. cheers